# Is it possible to have space between cells in iTextPdf?

Tags: java, itext, itextpdf, pdfptable

Does iTextPdf allow to set spacing between cells in table?

I have a table with 2 columns and I am trying to draw a border-bottom on cell.
I want space between each border same as cell padding.

I am using below code:

```
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.setTotalWidth(95f);
    table.setWidths(new float[]{0.5f,0.5f});
    table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

    Font fontNormal10 = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, Font.NORMAL);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Performance", fontNormal10));
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    cell.setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
    cell.setPaddingLeft(10f);
    cell.setPaddingRight(10f);

    table.addCell(cell);
    table.addCell(cell);
    table.addCell(cell);
    table.addCell(cell);

    document.add(table);
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want this effect:

[image]

That is explained in [my book](http://itextpdf.com/book), more specifically in the [PressPreviews](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=95) example.

You need to remove the borders first:

```
cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
```

And you need to draw the border yourself in a cell event:

```
public class MyBorder implements PdfPCellEvent {
    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position,
        PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        float x1 = position.getLeft() + 2;
        float x2 = position.getRight() - 2;
        float y1 = position.getTop() - 2;
        float y2 = position.getBottom() + 2;
        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
        canvas.rectangle(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
        canvas.stroke();
    }
}
```

You declare the cell event to the cell like this:

```
cell.setCellEvent(new MyBorder());
```

In my example, I add or subtract 2 user units from the cell's dimensions. In your case, you could define a padding `p` and then add or subtract `p / 2` from the cell dimensions in your `PdfPCellEvent` implementation.

Comment: @Jens Any idea how i could only display the inner rectangles in the example above and not include the outer table?

Comment: @ericleit What do you mean with "inner rectangle"?

Comment: @Jens I meant the cell level borders as opposed to the table level border but i figured it out by setting the table border to 0. Thanks for the reply!